# how to use pipe between child and parent processes

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, pipe, fork

This is a part of my program where the parent process creates a pipe and fork and passes the number form the parent to the child using a pipe.

The problem that pipe and forks does not work in the main in addition to the conversion from integers char!

```
#include <iostream>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <unistd.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <string.h>

#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
        int arr[20];
        char arrCH[20];


        //print process id
        cout << "The current process id is: " << getpid() << endl;

        //random value
        int N = rand()% 10;

        cout << "The genrated random value is: " << N << endl;
        for (int i=1;i<N;i++)
        {
                arr[i] = rand()% 10;
                arrCH[i] = (char)arr[i]; //somthing wrong

        }


        //create a pipe
        int p1[2];
        pipe(p1);

        close(p1[0]);
        write(p1[1],arrCH,strlen(arrCH)+1);

        int r = fork(); //creat a child
        if(r==0)
        {
                cout << "**The fist child**" <<endl;
                close(p1[1]);
                read(p1[0],arrCH,strlen(arrCH));

                //sort the numbers
                //creat another pipe
                //send the sorted numbers to the second child using another pipe

                int r2 = fork();
                if(r2 == 0)
                {
                        cout << "**The second child**" <<endl;

                }
                else
                {
                        wait(NULL);

                 }

                exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
                wait(NULL);

        }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you may get a better response if you tag this with `C`... I'm assuming it's C anyway...

Comment: You need to close the reading end of the pipe in the parent AFTER you fork. You should postpone writing to p[1] until that moment too, because if you exceed the pipe buffer, writing will turn into a blocking operation, causing your code to deadlock (the reader will not have been forked yet).

Comment: Also, since you're treating arrCH as a string, you should put an explicit '\0' after the characters your write, because auto data on the stack aren't technically guaranteed to be have been zeroed, though they will be, if you're just starting out and there's no chance they get allocated in a part of the stack your code already was at.

Comment: That's an impressive list of includes. Might be worth including `stdlib` a fourth time just in case.